# GCM - Max length for Registration ID

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

> **Update:** [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is deprecated, use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

What is the maximum length for a Registration ID issued by GCM servers? GCM documentation do not provide this info. Googling for this reveals that Registration ID is not fixed length in nature and can be up to 4K (4096 bytes) in length. But these are not official answers from Google. I am currently receiving Registration IDs which are 162 characters long. Can anybody help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android GCM registration ID max length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324666/android-gcm-registration-id-max-length)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am interested in know about this also. My reg id size is 183 chars. I suspect it won't be longer than 512 chars though, let alone 4K. Imagine sending bulk notification, a 4K reg id x 1000 = 4MB message size!

In the end, I just use the 'text' type in my MySQL table to store the registration id. So even if google send me a 1K, 2K, or 4K (very unlikely) reg id, I will be able to handle it.

Update: I have come across a new reg id size: 205.

Comment: so the max gcmId length is 512 characters?

Comment: That's the thing, we don't know how long it could be. So far the longest I have seen is 205 characters. Perhaps others can chime in if they've seen a longer one.

Comment: Your package name for your app has an effect on the size. In my testing, we've seen that by reducing the package length, it reduces the size of the registration token sent from GCM.

Comment: Using "text" type in your MySql table won't let you create an index for it.

Comment: what about storing the MD5(reg_id)? 32 chars, unique. in addition of indexing this is the good solution as for me, at least it looks like. Of course you could also store the original key however use Hashed key for all the operations.

Comment: @stan Out of curiosity, what is GCM registration ID good for apart sending messages? More specifically, what is its hash good for?

Comment: @Pius For indexing on server's DB like MySQL?

Comment: @Stan I think using Android ID is better because it has a fixed length + can be used for identifying devices which is almost always what you need to search by.

Comment: omg. Can't you understand - its about storing tons of user's GCM IDs on server and indexing them?

Answer (score 42):

On android-gcm forum a google's developer [confirms](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-gcm/q2PzJTP71TY/DNX4lvDu5X4J) it's 4k

Comment: Another thread, same answer from a Google developer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-c2dm/AUGlvmJPyMM Just as confirmation...

Comment: they can confirm whatever they want!
the only thing a developer needs is a decent documentation on this value... is that so hard? that's how you get bugs in an application when you are expecting DB entry of 255 chars (reasonable value but not a fact) and you receive > 255 later on...

Comment: Reading on the same google group post, it seems it was a mistake, 4k is the limit for the payload of the message, not the reg id. 255 seems to be the safe limit, also acording to this post.

Comment: I did varchar(512) just to be safe :P

Comment: This is the payload, not the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is what has said in GCM doc,

A JSON object whose fields represents the key-value pairs of the message's payload data. If present, the payload data it will be included in the Intent as application data, with the key being the extra's name. For instance, "data":{"score":"3x1"} would result in an intent extra named score whose value is the string 3x1.

There is no limit on the number of key/value pairs, though there is a limit on the total size of the message (4kb). The values could be any JSON object, but we recommend using strings, since the values will be converted to strings in the GCM server anyway.

If you want to include objects or other non-string data types (such as integers or booleans), you have to do the conversion to string yourself. Also note that the key cannot be a reserved word (from or any word starting with google.).

To complicate things slightly, there are some reserved words (such as collapse_key) that are technically allowed in payload data. However, if the request also contains the word, the value in the request will overwrite the value in the payload data. Hence using words that are defined as field names in this table is not recommended, even in cases where they are technically allowed. Optional.

Comment: This refers to the notification payload, not the registration id.