# GCM Registration Id maximum length

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

can any one confirm or provide any efficient document regarding the maximum length of Registration Id
for GCM?

Comment: 163 Characters I guess

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question has been asked before. See the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13713128/1856717