# Codename One Push Notification Key Length

Tags: sql, push, codenameone

How long should my push notification key length be in the database assuming I use a `VARCHAR` and want to pre-determine its length?

This is referring to the new push notification and not the old server where the id was numeric:

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-push-servers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problematic since the [Codename One push notification](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-push-servers.html) key is effectively structured as `cn1-gcm-nativekey`, `cn1-ios-nativekey` etc...

The variable here is the nativekey, on iOS its length is fixed to 32 but in Android [it can theoretically reach 4K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324666/android-gcm-registration-id-max-length).

Realistically Android push keys are currently well below 200 chars but they might grow in length and you should add the 8 chars in length that Codename One needs so too be 100% secure for the future you would need 4104 characters but you can probably get away with 250 and be really safe with 500.